# What is the right protein for me? I'm struggling to find one

Tags: muscle, gym, protein

I am a 14 year old athlete who plays football at academy and also internationally with a few caps. My pre-season has started and I need some protein to assist with my training and training goals. I need to stay lean, keep my body fat % really low. I need to become stronger but I must stay lean and athletic. What is the right protein for me? Please could you give some examples?

Answer (score 2):

Any protein you get from meat and dairy.

You are 14 years old and not fully developed, which means that if you are even semi-aware of what you eat, you'll reap huge benefits.

Just eat what your parents serve you, and finish your vegetables!